# firebase updateProfile() only changes data to firestore after signing in again

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to save the "score" variable to the "highscore" field in my cloud firestore database for my user but the change only appears after I sign in again using google. Everytime I sign in, there is also a new document being created even though I am signing in with the same google account. I did this while updating a standard collection like "displayName" but the custom collection I have set "highscore" could never be updated, not even after signing in again. I have tried reloading the user but it doesn't do anything. (I am using the namespaced web version 8 in vanilla.js)

This is my code:

```js
function gameOver () {
  if (score > highscore) {
    GAME_OVER_TEXT.innerText = 'New Highscore:';
    HIGHSCORE.innerText = `${score} points.`;
    STARS.classList.remove('hide');
    SPARKLE.classList.remove('hide');
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.updateProfile({
      highscore: score
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Update successful');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Update unsuccessful' + error);
    });  
    user.currentUser.reload();
  } else {
    GAME_OVER_TEXT.innerText = 'Your score:';
    HIGHSCORE.innerText = `${score} points.`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `reload` immediately loads the current profile from the server. Since `updateProfile` is also an asynchronous call, you are now loading the un-updated profile. To fix this, you have to reload the profile after the update has completed. So:

```
user.updateProfile({
  highscore: score
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Update successful');
  user.currentUser.reload().then(() => {
    console.log('Profile reloaded');
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Update unsuccessful' + error);
});
```

---

Note that `updateProfile` only accepts `displayName` and `photoURL` as properties, as you can't store other information in the user profile from the Firebase client-side SDKs. You can either use an Admin SDK (on a server or otherwise trusted environment) to set a custom claim with that value, or (more likely here) store the information in a custom database (such as Firestore or Realtime Database, which as also part of Firebase).

This has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out previous [questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+store+additional+user+properties).